# No Operacional System Android is Installed

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, twrp, fastboot, motorola-moto-e

I was trying to install the ROM [system-squeak-arm64-ab-gogapps](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/releases/tag/v416) from the project [treble_experimentations](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations) and I reported some of this in this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253577/i-cant-list-zipped-images-in-twrp), however, It may not be so now.

In short, in my whole process of trying to install the new ROM, I happen to think that at some point things were "wiped" more than I expected, now TWRP says that I don't have any system installed and when I start the **Moto E5 Plus** it just always drops to the bootloader screen and that's it. Even after I flashed the image on the MicroSD inserted into the device and the process says everything was ok, the bootloader screen doesn't advance, it's as if nothing had happened.

Comment: I think I expressed myself wrong, sorry. I did not install the operating system on MicroSD, but the image for installing the operating system was to be installed on my device was on MicroSD.